# Chrome dev-tools extension unable to get promise back with inspectedWindow.eval

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to access a function from devtools which exists on the window.
I'm using the `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval` function.

Window:

```
window.__api__ = {
  getResult: function() {
    return [1,2,3]
  },

  getResultPromise: function() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve([1,2,3]))
  }

};
```

DevTools:

```
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(
      '__api__.getResult()',
      (result, isException) => {
        if (isException) {
          console.log('Error')
          return
        }

        console.log(result)
      }
    );
```

When I'm calling `getResult()` it returns the array [1,2,3]. But, when i'm calling `getResultPromise` it returns an empty object. Doesn't matter if I'm also doing an `await` or anything.. it just doesn't return the promise value.

How can I work with promises and get the data then?

Comment: See the documentation: only JSON-compatible portion will be transferred. Meaning number, string, boolean, null, or arrays/objects of such types. Not `Promise`.

Comment: @wOxxOm so how can I deal with promises? 
I thought I could eval 'await __api__.getResult()', still this didn't work.

Comment: Since Promise isn't a JSON-compatible type, you can't return a Promise. Also, await is just a syntax sugar on top of Promise. You'll have to use content scripts and messaging.